# Decoding words in Latin

Tags: paleography

It is very necessary to decipher the words in Latin. The text of the manuscript of the 13th century[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ampne *[= amne]* parit pueros elephas draco ne necet illos
>
> Ne draco predetur *[= praedetur]* animas baptisma tuetur.

I'll admit I couldn't decipher all of the words (*elephas* in particular is illegible, and it's kind of an important word), but it looks like it's an excerpt from the Latin translation of the *Physiologus*, which is how I managed to fill in the blanks.

My translation:

> The elephant births its children in the river, so that the dragon does not kill them.
>
> So that the dragon not prey on their souls, it performs a baptism.